# how to set up reverse proxy server using XAMPP in windows

Tags: apache, xampp, reverse-proxy

I am trying to set up a reverse proxy server in XAMPP to avoid the CORS error which occurs when i try to access an API running on a different port.
I have made these changes to my files.

The details of the API are:

- host=http://127.0.0.1
- port=8002

httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:8002>
    ProxyRequests On
    <Proxy>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</VirtualHost>
```

httpd-proxy.conf

```
<IfModule proxy_module>
<IfModule proxy_http_module>

#
# Reverse Proxy
#
ProxyRequests Off

<Proxy *>
      Require all granted
</Proxy>

</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

httpd.conf

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

When I start my Apache server, it does not start and throws an error:

> Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.

```
15:00:12  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
15:00:12  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
15:00:12  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
15:00:12  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
15:00:12  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
15:00:12  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
```

Should I continue with XAMPP or use nginx for setting up reverse proxy?

Comment: Did you look at the logs or windows event viewer like the text you pasted here tells you to do?

Comment: @JamesZ i looked at the logs but was not able to figure out. it shows the last accessed pages before making the above changes.